# Blogs, wikis and discussion forums in an internet publishing site

Tags: blog, wiki, collaboration, publishing-site

I have blogs, wikis and discussion forums module in my SharePoint publishing site.

How can I use the SharePoint web parts for these modules? Should I activate the collaboration feature on this site? And if I activate the Collaboration feature will it cause a security issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive this is what you are asking, but what I can tell is that you have a site collection that is using the publishing site template and you want to create blogs, wikis, and discussion forums within this site collection. The only way I know of to create these in a publishing site collection is to use the command line: stsadm.exe -o createweb -url http://publishingsiteurl/addnewwebhere -sitetemplate  -title

The template names could be BLOG#0 or WIKI#0 as for the discussion forum, you can use STS#1 and create a blank site and add the discussion boards.

Hope this helps!